# unique records in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

how to find all the unique records in elastic search based on an attribute in it..
Is there a way?

```
GET  questiondetails/question/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "Name" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "owner.user_id.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this way.. But I want it to give all the docs wherever user id is present in the whole record.
Whether it is in inner loop also....

Is there a way to get this in a single query instead of making in multiple queries..
Here is my sample record.

```
{
    "_index": "questiondetails",
    "_type": "question",
    "_id": "BOktPnABW1evGoA0CqDZ",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "tags": [
        "android",
        "kotlin"
      ],
      "owner": {

        "user_id": "10633771"
      },

      "reply_count": "1",

      "reply": [
        {
          "owner": {

            "user_id": "12632101",
            "user_type": "registered",

          }

        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Index

```
{
  "questiondetails": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "question": {
        "properties": {
          "accepted_answer_id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "answer_count": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "answers": {
            "properties": {
              "answer_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "body": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "body_markdown": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "comment_count": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "comments": {
                "properties": {
                  "comment_id": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "creation_date": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "edited": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  },
                  "owner": {
                    "properties": {
                      "accept_rate": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "display_name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "link": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "profile_image": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "reputation": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "user_id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "user_type": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "post_id": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "reply_to_user": {
                    "properties": {
                      "display_name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "link": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "profile_image": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "reputation": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "user_id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "user_type": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "score": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "creation_date": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "down_vote_count": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "is_accepted": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "last_activity_date": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "last_edit_date": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "link": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "owner": {
                "properties": {
                  "accept_rate": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "display_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "link": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "profile_image": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "reputation": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "user_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "user_type": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "question_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "score": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "share_link": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "up_vote_count": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "body": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "body_markdown": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "close_vote_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "comment_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "comments": {
            "properties": {
              "body": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "body_markdown": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "comment_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "creation_date": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "edited": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "owner": {
                "properties": {
                  "accept_rate": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "display_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "link": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "profile_image": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "reputation": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "user_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "user_type": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "post_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "reply_to_user": {
                "properties": {
                  "accept_rate": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "display_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "link": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "profile_image": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "reputation": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "user_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "user_type": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "score": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "creation_date": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "delete_vote_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "down_vote_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "is_answered": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "last_activity_date": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "last_edit_date": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "last_editor": {
            "properties": {
              "accept_rate": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "display_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "link": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "profile_image": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "reputation": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "user_id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "user_type": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "link": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "owner": {
            "properties": {
              "accept_rate": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "display_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "link": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "profile_image": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "reputation": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "user_id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "user_type": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "question_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "reopen_vote_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "score": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "share_link": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "up_vote_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "view_count": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1581585452123",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "_nvo_G7ZRvqMIwLmddUXPw",
        "version": {
          "created": "6020399"
        },
        "provided_name": "questiondetails"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index using `GET questiondetails` please?

Comment: GET questiondetails/question/_search

Comment: No, `GET questiondetails` I want to see your index mapping

Comment: Are you saying that you want to see my data?? 
 Shall i run getquestiondetails  and give you data?h

Comment: Not the data, just the index mapping, just run `GET questiondetails` in KIbana Dev Tools and update your question with the results you get.

Comment: I am not able to keep that in question....Its bit big and on top of that i am getting this error .


Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Ok, then I just need the mapping of the `reply` array field

Comment: Even that is not happening .. same issue.

Can i send it to you in any mail or something ?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting your mapping and not actual data? I doubt that your mapping can be that big

Comment: { "questiondetails": { "aliases": {}, "mappings": { "question": { "properties": { "owner": { "properties": { "user_id": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } } } }, "reply": { "properties": { "owner": { "properties": { "user_id": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "user_type": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } } } } } }, "reply_count": { "type": "text", "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } } } } } } }

Comment: created  a similar small table and sending you the index..
Please have a look

Comment: Please do not post that in comments and update your question as it's more legible

Comment: Added the index at the bottom in the question with heading index..

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with a [scripted `terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script), like this:

```
POST questions/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "[doc['owner.user_id.keyword'].value, doc['reply.owner.user_id.keyword'].value]",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```